# Curve fitting on small and dense dataset as straight as possible

Tags: polynomials, optimization, regression, least-squares, linear-regression

I have to fit a 3rd degree polynomial on a small and dense dataset. I've used polynomial regression and least square error, but the result is undesirable. I will explain why.

Let the polynomial be:
$$y = c_0+c_1x+\frac{1}{2}c_2x^2+\frac{1}{6}c_3x^3$$

And the dataset:
$$x = [27, 32, 33, 34, 35, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43]$$
$$y = [29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 29, 29, 29]$$

By applying polynomial regression, I get

[image]

I understand that this is absolutely correct. It fits on my data. But the desired behavior on this kind of points is as follows (made by hand)

[image]

Also, if the points describe a curvature, the resulting polynomial should follow that curvature.

What I **can't** do to get to this result

- Modify input dataset
- Modify ecuation

What I **can** do

- Modify anything about polynomial regression (like error function)
- Replace polynomial regression

I've also tried Levenberg-Marquardt, but as expected the results are the same as polynomial regression.

Comment: You want to have a linear look on your solution, but you use a cubic? Why not simply estimate a linear function?

Comment: @JohanLöfberg, sometimes I will receive points that can be described the best using this function. I don't know when I will receive this kind of points. That's why I'm forced to use it.

Comment: Then I would use $\ell_1$ as it appears more robust for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the trivial solution to simply use an affine model instead of a cubic, if you switch from a quadratic residual to absolute value, you will obtain a affine response.

With absolute values, called $\ell_1$, the solution is typically less sensitive to outliers, and in your case the two values of $30$ will effectively be seen as outliers and the $\ell_1$-optimal solution is $y(x) = 29$.

The  $\ell_1$ model can be cast as a linear program by noting that minimizing $\sum |e_i|$ can be written as minimize $\sum t_i$ subject to $-t_i \leq e_i \leq t_i$.

Comment: Interesting. After a few examples over the internet it may be promising. I will try to implement this and I will come back with feedback. Thank you.

Comment: Note that I fixed a typo in the LP formulation (removed absolute value)

Answer (score 0):

For sure, the cubic fits your data as shown below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 x & y & \text{calc}\\
 27 & 29 & 29.030 \\
 32 & 29 & 28.832 \\
 33 & 29 & 28.938 \\
 34 & 29 & 29.063 \\
 35 & 29 & 29.193 \\
 38 & 29 & 29.490 \\
 39 & 30 & 29.514 \\
 40 & 30 & 29.480 \\
 41 & 29 & 29.375 \\
 42 & 29 & 29.186 \\
 43 & 29 & 28.899
\end{array}
\right)$$ The problem is that, for the parameters, one can obtain
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 c_0 & 112.129 & 52.7599 & \{-16.9699,241.228\} \\
 c_1 & -7.49163 & 4.64423 & \{-18.8557,3.87239\} \\
 c_2 & 0.442603 & 0.269298 & \{-0.216346,1.10155\} \\
 c_3 & -0.0128499 & 0.00771852 & \{-0.0317365,0.00603661\} \\
\end{array}$$ and none of them is significant.